# VSCode: How to enable links in a webpage in the Webview

Tags: typescript, webview, visual-studio-code, autohotkey, vscode-extensions

`vscode.previewHtml` got deprecatd in favour of Webview.
I updated my [ahk extension for vscode](https://github.com/Denis-net/vscode-ahk-manager) using this new API.
With `hh.exe -decompile Docs AutoHotkey.chm` I got a local website version of the main AutoHotkey site.
I wanted to show in the second column a contextual docs so you can read about it while coding. So I did.
I successfully managed to load the page with the stylesheet, 
but the links don't work : I stay always on the same page.

Even if I can alter theire href I'm not able to go to another page.
Althought you can read in tooltip the href value, every time you click on a link nothing happens.
The Docs folder is stored inside the extension path, so the `localResourceRoots` should be fine.

A strange thing that i noted is that even with `enableScripts` is set to true, it seems that not all the js code is executed, because on the AutoHotkey webSite, in the .chm and in every .html files opened with FF I can see the sidebar, but not in the WebView page.

This is the code for creating the WebView:

```
 this.docsPanel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel('ahk-offline-docs', 'Documentation', { viewColumn: vscode.ViewColumn.Two, preserveFocus: true }, {
                enableScripts: true,
                enableFindWidget: true,
                enableCommandUris: true,
                localResourceRoots: [vscode.Uri.file(path.join(this.docsDirectoryPath, 'docs//')).with({ scheme: 'vscode-resource' })]
            });
            this.docsPanel.onDidDispose((e) => {
                this.isDocsPanelDisposed = true;
            });
```

And this is the code that loads the page into the WebView:

```
let url = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(this.docsDirectoryPath, 'docs/')).with({ scheme: 'vscode-resource' });
                    const dom = new JSDOM(data, { runScripts: "dangerously" });
                    const aTags = dom.window.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
                    const len = aTags.length;
                    const basePath = url.toString();
                    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        const a = aTags[i];
                        if (!a.href.includes('about:blank')) {
                            const commentCommandUri = vscode.Uri.parse(`command:ahk.spy`);
                            a.href = basePath + a.href;
                            // a.removeAttribute('href');
                            // a.setAttribute('onclick', '{command:ahk.spy}');
                        }
                    }
                    let ser = dom.serialize();
                    this.docsPanel.webview.html = /*data/*ser*/ser.toString().replace('<head>', `<head>\n<base href="${url.toString()}/">`);
```

An alternative idea was to launch vscode.commands from the page (because of `enableCommandUris`) but I didn't get how to do this kind of operation.

If you need/want to reproduce this issue you just have to clone the repo, going into the `improving-offline-docs` branch and open the file `offline-docs-manager.ts`, the method is `openTheDocsPanel()`

Is there a way to switch the current page using links ?
Should I develop a postMessage system ?
or I missed a settings somewhere ?
or is there an even better way for doing it ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webviews can not navigate to another page inside the current webview. If your webview tries to do so, you should see a message such as `prevented webview navigation` inside the webview developer tools

There are two ways to handle links in webviews:

- `<a>` elements that link to external resource—such a `https:` or `mailto:` links—should work in most cases. There may be a few weird edge cases, and if you run into one of these you'd want to use either a `command` uri or `postMessage` to trigger some action in your main extension's source
- If you want to update the webview content itself and cannot do this within the webview itself for some reasons, use either a `command` uri or `postMessage` to call some function in your main extension's source that update's the webview's html

Comment: Hey Matt Bierner,
Thank you for the reply !
How can i make a command with arg work ?
`let dom = new JSDOM(data, { runScripts: "dangerously" });
                    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        if (!a.href.includes('about:blank')) {
                            const commentCommandUri = vscode.Uri.parse(`command:ahk.docs?${basePath + a.href}`);
                            a.href = commentCommandUri.toString();}}
                    let html = dom.serialize();
`
I tried encoding `ahk.spy` command, but don't work.
Where can I found examples with _command_ ?

Comment: [Documentation on command URIs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#command-uris). The key is using a json stringified array and using `encodeURIComponent`